# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig when I upgraded to Spring-boot 2.7

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, httpclient, spring-webflux

I am getting this error upon building my project and I am not sure why. I only got it when I upgraded my Spring boot version to 2.7.2. It says in my error below

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig
> at com.web.info.DataClientTest.setup(DataClientTest .java:42)

I've already got this in my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test.project.data</groupId>
<artifactId>data-test-project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <formatter-file.location>${project.basedir}/formatter/eclipse-formatter-config.xml</formatter-file.location>
    <testcontainers.version>1.10.6</testcontainers.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Security Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>
            spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner
        </artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-wiremock</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
        <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.marvinformatics.formatter</groupId>
            <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <configFile>${formatter-file.location}</configFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
            <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <threads>8</threads>
                <coverageThreshold>73</coverageThreshold>
                <failWhenNoMutations>true</failWhenNoMutations>
                <mutationThreshold>68</mutationThreshold>
                <excludedMethods>
                    <excludedMethod>hashCode</excludedMethod>
                    <excludedMethod>toString</excludedMethod>
                    <excludedMethod>equals</excludedMethod>
                </excludedMethods>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my DataClientTest class:

```
class DataClientTest {
  
        private DataClient dataClient;
    
        private ObjectMapper mapper;
        private WireMockServer wireMockServer;
    
        @BeforeEach
        void setup() {
            final DataProcessorProperties properties = new DataProcessorProperties ();
            properties.getData().setUrl("http://localhost:8080");
            mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
            wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8080);
            wireMockServer.start();
            statDataClient = new DataClient(WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080"), properties);
    
        }
    
        @AfterEach
        void shutdown() {
            wireMockServer.stop();
        }
    
        @Test
        void testGetData() throws Exception {
    
            final String jsonRecord = mapper.writeValueAsString(sampleData());
            wireMockServer.addStubMapping(get(urlPathMatching("/v1/data"))
                    .withHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, equalTo("application/json"))
                    .willReturn(okJson(jsonRecord).withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"))
                    .withQueryParam("id", equalTo("123456789")).build());
    
            final Optional<List<ReportData>> result = this.dataClient
                    .getRecordData(123456789);
    
            wireMockServer.verify(getRequestedFor(WireMock.urlPathEqualTo("/v1/data"))
                    .withHeader("Accept", equalTo("application/json")).withQueryParam("id", equalTo("123456789")));
    
            assertThat(result.isPresent()).isTrue();
            assertThat(result.get().size()).isEqualTo(2);
        }
}
```

The part where the error is pointing is at this line:

```
DataClient(WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080"), properties);
```

Do I need to add or update something from my pom.xml? Thanks!

Comment: show us your full pom

Comment: hello @Toerktumlare, I updated the pom.xml

Comment: Can you share your DataClient class?